# I want to make a sticky side-bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've made the sidebar, but I want the sidebar to be fixed and also have a vertical scroll bar.
This is what I want:[image: I want the sidebar to be sticky and also have a scrollbar.]

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<div class="col-md-4 bg-light px-0">
                <div class="sidebar px-3">
                    <h3 class="mt-4">Rental</h3>
                    <h3 class="mt-2">from $99</h3>
                    <p class="mb-5">per night</p>
                    <form action="">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o pr-1"></i>Check in</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD MM YYYY" required>
                        </div>
                        <p class=""><i class="fa fa-calendar-o pr-1"></i>Check out</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD MM YYYY" required>
                        </div>
                        <p class=""><i class="fa fa-male pr-1"></i>Adults</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="1" required>
                        </div>
                        <p class=""><i class="fa fa-child pr-1"></i>Kids</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success w-100"><i
                                    class="fa fa-search pr-3"></i> Search availability</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="hoverablediv">
                    <div class="py-3 p-3"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-dark"><i
                                class="fa fa-building pr-1"></i>Apartment</a></div>
                    <div class="py-3 p-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#"
                            class="text-decoration-none text-dark"><i class="fa fa-rss pr-1"></i>Subscribe</a></div>
                    <div class="py-3 p-3"><a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-dark"><i
                                class="fa fa-envelope pr-1"></i>Contact</a></div>
                </div>
                
            </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your body has a `z-index` value of 0, add

```css
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1;
```

or this (if you want the sidebar to always have a vertical scrollbar)

```css
position: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
z-index: 1;
```

to your sidebar's css

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Did the scrollbar not appear? What position property does the sidebar have?

Comment: The scrollbar does not appear and it does not have any position property.

Comment: The title of this post says you want the sidebar to be sticky, but in the post you say you want it to be fixed. Those are two different things, which one exactly do you want?
You can read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Ok, I want it to be fixed, please.

Comment: Try adding `position: fixed;` and `overflow: auto;` or `overflow-y: scroll;` and see if that works the way you want it to.

Comment: `display: fixed` is not a valid property for display. Either you mean `position: fixed` or `display: block`

Comment: @NHerwich it works but the main body is now displayed on top of the sidebar.

Comment: The sidebar needs a `z-index` higher than the one of the body.
Assuming you didn't assign your body a `z-index` value, giving the sidebar `z-index: 1` should put it back on top.

Comment: @cloned You're right, I meant `position: fixed`. I corrected it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237171/discussion-between-samuel-emeka-and-nherwich).